# Is it possible to detect the facial expressions during a video chat like skype, and show the smiley face with the same expression of the person?

Tags: video, skype

what I meant was detect the facial expressions of user 1 and show the emoticons to user 2 instead of the face, with the same expressions of user 1 during a video chat through skype, face time etc. Its actually for a project. Thanks

Comment: You might want to try the StackExchange site itself which is about programming. Unless Skype supports this natively (and I'm pretty sure it doesn't) you'll probably need to write this application yourself. A quick search doesn't show any specific application with this feature. Can it be done? Well, probably with varied levels of accuracy and training. Can it be done easily? Probably not if you're asking here. You'll probably have better luck using the StackExchange link at the top of this page.

Comment: ... something like this perhaps: [facial expression classification in real time using SVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640804/facial-expression-classification-in-real-time-using-svm)